# OpenSSL: socket: Connection refused connect:errno=111 Cent OS

Tags: centos, ssl, openssl, tls

I'm facing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33340332/how-to-enable-tls-1-2-in-nginx) problem.Actually I'm trying to disable SSLV3 and enable TLS 1.2 in my Cent OS production server.I found exact same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27312068/openssl-socket-connection-refused-connecterrno-111).

```
[root@186-aven-vps ~]# openssl s_client -connect kickmarket.eu:443 -ssl3
socket: Connection refused
connect:errno=111
```

So I tried accepted answer in the above mentioned link

```
[root@186-aven-vps ~]# nmap kickmarket.eu

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-10-27 04:16 GMT
Nmap scan report for kickmarket.eu (46.4.213.86)
Host is up (0.000010s latency).
rDNS record for 46.4.213.86: 186-aven-vps.mde.ie
Not shown: 986 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
21/tcp    open  ftp
22/tcp    open  ssh
25/tcp    open  smtp
53/tcp    open  domain
80/tcp    open  http
110/tcp   open  pop3
143/tcp   open  imap
465/tcp   open  smtps
587/tcp   open  submission
993/tcp   open  imaps
995/tcp   open  pop3s
3306/tcp  open  mysql
10000/tcp open  snet-sensor-mgmt
20000/tcp open  dnp

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.10 seconds
```

But couldn't see the openssl running on port 443.Here is my some information

```
[root@186-aven-vps ~]# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

[root@186-aven-vps ~]# yum info openssl
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.softaculous.com
 * epel: mirrors.n-ix.net
 * extras: centosmirror.netcup.net
 * rpmforge: mirror.de.leaseweb.net
 * updates: mirror.23media.de
Installed Packages
Name        : openssl
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 1.0.1e
Release     : 42.el7.9
Size        : 1.5 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : updates
Summary     : Utilities from the general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
URL         : http://www.openssl.org/
License     : OpenSSL
Description : The OpenSSL toolkit provides support for secure communications between
            : machines. OpenSSL includes a certificate management tool and shared
            : libraries which provide various cryptographic algorithms and
            : protocols.
```

Comment: What are you trying to connect to exactly? Nginx?

Comment: @David please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168251/opensslsslsslerror-ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-c

Comment: I still can't figure out what you're trying to do. Why would you expect OpenSSL to be running on port 443? What are you trying to connect to with OpenSSL? I understand the broad concept of what you're trying to do, but can't for the life of me figure out what the specific issue you're having has to do with your big picture. Are you trying to configure nginx? If so, to do what? To listen on port 443?

Answer (score 1):

Since the connection is refused there is either no server at this address or a firewall is blocking the connection. Not much more can be said from the information you provide but

- Check that you actually have a server running at port 443: `netstat -lnt` on the server machine will tell you if there is some server at port 443.
- If there is no server make sure you have it correctly configured (look for error messages)

Comment: Thank you @Steffen.It seems their is problem with my configuration.One thing I got confused is Do I need to use HTTPS SSL in order to call Paypal Sandbox API?

Comment: @BibekSharma: I have no idea of how this API works.